# What is the mysql command to "go back one step"

Tags: mysql, sql

What I mean is I can access my database by executing the following commands one by one:

```
mysql -r root

mysql> show databases;

mysql> use database my_db_one;

mysql> show tables;

mysql> describe table my_table_one

...
```

But, after each of the above step, how to go one step back? What is the command for that?

I mean for example, after I `describe table my_table_one`, I want to show all databases again and use another database, how to go back in command line?

Comment: are you just missing a trailing ; on the last command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is none, but none is necessary. With the exception of `USE` (which always changes your current database to the one you specify), the MySQL command line is (largely) stateless, so you can always repeat a command you used earlier or try something different:

```
[...]
mysql> describe my_table_one;
mysql> show tables; -- again
mysql> describe my_table_two;
mysql> show databases; -- again
mysql> use my_db_two;
mysql> ...
```

Comment: What is the exception of USE? Can you explain?

Comment: `USE` is an exception here because it changes the database that all following commands will apply to (so, for instance, you can't repeat a `DESCRIBE` or `SELECT` which refers to a table which was in a database you switched away from, and `SHOW TABLES` will show different tables).

Comment: @Leem The SQL CLI isn't really like the UNIX command line. The tables aren't like individual directories - this means that you don't have to back out of them. So if you do a `SHOW TABLE my_table_1`, it's not like doing a `cd my_table_1` in unix - it's more like an `ls my_table_1`. The SQL `USE` command is different because it actually selects a database; doing `USE my_database` is closer to doing `cd my_database` in unix. I hope that made some more sense.

Comment: Hi, actually, I know the meaning of the exception, that's I knew already your explanation when you said "there is a exception of USE" before you explain. What I ask is how to get rid of this exception, if I do not want to login to mySQL again to access other database after I used "USE". I mean how to use other database after I have already INSIDE one database.

Comment: Just go ahead and `USE` the other database. There's no need to "back out" of the first database first, as `USE` switches you directly to the database you specify.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to stop USEing a database and go back to no database, other than ending the session, so SHOW DATABASES will work again?

Comment: @Noumenon No, but you don't have to. `SHOW DATABASES` works regardless of whether you've already selected a database.